# Failed to scaffold REACT Application in Coursera

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, npm, yarnpkg

I am learning the Frontend development course on Coursera. Currently, I am learning the second module of the course "Frontend Development with React".

I have followed all the instructions as given in the website as follows:

`yarn global add create-react-app@1.5.2`

`create-react-app confusion`

`npm run --lite`

But nothing happens.Can anyone please help me out as to what is going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The current version of create-react-app is 4.0.3, you should find a more up-to-date guide.

Comment: Now the preferred way of using create-react-app is to use  npx: npx create-react-app confusion

Comment: Why not start out from the tutorial given in react's site itself https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html